# Choose a random SpriteNode out of an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, random

I'm learning how to code and as a first project I thought it would be a good idea to create a little stone paper scissors game against the computer. The problem is, that obviously the computer may not show his choice, so I have to create a function, which makes a random picture x (I'm using Apple's smileys for it) appear on the position x on the screen.

So I have to:

1. random number between 1 and 3 `var rN = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 3)`
2. `let array = [opStone, opPaper, opScissors] //already declared as files`
3. `let choiceOp = array[rN]`
4. `choiceOp.position = CGPoint(x. ?, y: ?)`
5. `self.addChild(choiceOp)`

In theory. The problem is, that Swift does not accept a `GKRandom` distributed number `rN` at the third step.

Do you have any ideas how I could do it?

Comment: If you are planing to use that random number as an array index it should be from 0 to 2 for an array of 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

In your step 3, you should call `nextInt()` on `rN`. `GKRandomDistribution` generates a new random number every time you call `nextInt()` based on the lowest and highest value you have given it at initialization. So your new code would be:

```
let choiceOp = array[rN.nextInt()]
```